# Query against sys.schemas and sys.synonyms runs very slow for one user

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, query-performance

Scenario: SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.4100.1)

.NET Service runs this query:

```
SELECT name, base_object_name 
FROM sys.synonyms 
WHERE schema_id IN (SELECT schema_id 
                    FROM sys.schemas 
                    WHERE name = N'XXXX')
ORDER BY name
```

...which returns about 6500 rows but it often times out after 3+ minutes. The `XXXX` above is *not* 'dbo'.

If I run this query in SSMS as UserA, the query returns in less than a second.

When run as UserB (which is how the .NET service connects), the query takes 3-6 *minutes*, and has the CPU% at 25% (of a 4 cores) the entire time.

UserA is a Domain Login in the sysadmin role.

UserB is a SQL Login with:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'UserB'
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'UserB'
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_ddladmin', N'UserB'
GRANT EXECUTE TO [UserB]
GRANT CREATE SCHEMA TO [UserB]
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [UserB]
```

I can duplicate this in SSMS by wrapping the above SQL in an `Execute as...Revert` block, so the .NET code is out of the picture.

The execution plan looks the same. I diff'ed the XML and there are only minor differences (CompileTime, CompileCPU, CompileMemory).

IO Stats all show no physical reads:

```
Table 'sysobjvalues'. Scan count 0, logical reads 19970, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 9122, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysclsobjs'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

XEvent waits status (for a ~3min query) are:

```
+---------------------+------------+----------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|      Wait Type      | Wait Count | Total Wait Time (ms) | Total Resource Wait Time (ms) | Total Signal Wait Time (ms) |
+---------------------+------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD |      37300 |                  427 |                            20 |                         407 |
| NETWORK_IO          |          5 |                   26 |                            26 |                           0 |
| IO_COMPLETION       |          3 |                    1 |                             1 |                           0 |
+---------------------+------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

If I rewrite the query (in SSMS, I don't have access to the App Code) to

```
declare @id int 
SELECT @id=schema_id FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = N'XXXX'
SELECT a.name, base_object_name FROM sys.synonyms a
WHERE schema_id = @id
ORDER BY name
```

then UserB runs at the same (fast) speed as UserA.

If I add `db_owner` to UserB, then, again, the query runs < 1 sec.

Schema created via this template:

```
DECLARE @TranName VARCHAR(20)
SELECT @TranName = 'MyTransaction'

BEGIN TRANSACTION @TranName
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
        WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = '{1}')
BEGIN
    EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA [{1}]')
    EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name='User', @value='{0}', @level0type=N'Schema', @level0name=N'{1}'
END
GO

{2}

COMMIT TRANSACTION MyTransaction;
GO
```

And {2} is, I believe, a list of Synonyms created in that schema.

Query Profile at two points into the query:

[image]

[image]

I've opened a ticket with Microsoft.

Also, we tried adding UserB to `db_owner`, and then `DENY`ing all of the privileges we know that are associated with `db_owner`.  The result is a fast query.  Either we missed something (entirely possible), or there is a special check for the `db_owner` role.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to re-write your query as follows (I'm using `dbo` rather than `XXXX` so that I do find some synonyms on my testing database). This is similar to the re-write you found to be more efficient, but avoids the need to declare a variable and use two queries.

```
SELECT name, base_object_name 
FROM sys.synonyms 
WHERE schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo')
ORDER BY name
```

This yields a plan like the following:

[image]

One very interesting thing about the `Filter` operator in this plan is that it has a predicate that performs an internal `has_access()` check. This filter removes any objects that the current account does not have sufficient permissions to see. However, this check is short-circuited (i.e., completes much more quickly) if you are a member of the `db_owner` role, which may explain the performance differences you are seeing.

[image]

Here is the query plan for your original query. Notice that all synonyms on the database (`1,126` in my case, but likely many more in your case) pass through the very expensive `has_access()` filter, even though only `2` synonyms match the schema. By using the simplified query above, we can ensure that `has_access()` is only invoked for the synonyms that match your query rather than for all synonyms in the database.

[image]

**Using sys.dm_exec_query_profiles to explore further**

As Martin suggests, we can confirm that the has_access() check is a significant bottleneck by using `sys.dm_exec_query_profiles` on SQL Server 2014+. If I run the following query using a `db_owner` account on a database with ~700K objects, the query takes `~500ms`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sys.objects
```

When run with an account that is not a `db_owner`, this same query takes about eight minutes! Running with actual plan on and using a [p_queryProgress](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/790addc34f44f4df3bf7ce799b08752d) procedure that I wrote to help parse `sys.dm_exec_query_profiles` output more easily, we can see that almost all of the processing time is spent on the `Filter` operator that is performing the `has_access()` check:

[image]

Comment: @MartinSmith I played around with a few different settings, going as high as the max `access check cache bucket count` of 65536 and a `access check cache quota` of 262144 (recommended 1:4 ratio), but for my query it did not have any significant impact on the `has_access()` performance either on the first try or on subsequent queries with a "warm cache"

Comment: @MartinSmith While those settings didn't have an impact, there is something interesting going on with the cache. It seems like the cache's existence is detrimental. E.g., if I run `WHILE(1=1) BEGIN DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('TokenAndPermUserStore') WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' END` in a loop forever, the query completes in under 2 minutes vs. 8 minutes typically.

Comment: Thanks everyone - the response back from Microsoft echos the comments above, and a query rewrite is the best solution.  It turns out that has_access() has a short-circuit at the beginning to test for db_owner or sysadmin and that resulted in the big time difference.

Answer (score 2):

We are able to reproduce the issue in SQL Server 2022.

#### SQL Server 2022 CU7 (48 cpu)

- For our trouble database, lots of permissions
- Run as 'domain end user'
- `SELECT * FROM sys.database_permissions`
  returns 2698 rows - Runtime of 1 min 6 seconds.
- Now run as me (sysadmin privilege – short circuit `has_access`)
  returns 212,887 rows in 2 seconds.

#### SQL Server 2016 SP3-CU1 (36 cpu)

- Backup restore trouble database to this environment, lots of permissions
- Run as 'domain end user'
- `SELECT * FROM sys.database_permissions`
  returns 2409 rows - Runtime of 3 seconds.
- Now run as me (sysadmin privilege – short circuit `has_access`)
  returns 212,711 rows in 1 seconds.

#### SQL Server 2019 (12 cpu)

- Backup restore trouble database to this environment, lots of permissions
- Run as 'domain end user'
- `SELECT * FROM sys.database_permissions`
  returns 2873 rows - Runtime of 5 seconds.
- Now run as me (sysadmin privilege – short circuit `has_access`)
  returns 212,711 rows in 2 seconds.

#### SQL Server 2022 CU10 (4 cpu) sandbox environment, no workload

- Backup restore trouble database to this environment, lots of permissions
- Run as 'domain end user'
- `SELECT * FROM sys.database_permissions`
  returns 2701 rows - Runtime of 34 seconds.
- Now run as me (sysadmin privilege – short circuit `has_access`)
  returns 212,732 rows in 4 seconds.

SQL Server 2016 and 2019 show very little performance penalty for end user permission lookup as part of a select on sys_permission or sys_columns or other system table, but SQL Server 2022 shows a massive performance impact for the same query.

This is due in part to a database with a large number of permissions (200k) however this was not an issue before we upgraded to 2022 as is shown in the 2016 numbers.

### Fix

Turning on trace flag 12502 in SQL Server 2022 appears to resolve the issue. Appears to be a bug in SQL Server that we have to "disable external authorization policies" as a workaround. I hope this can help someone else out there.

> [2351584](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2022/cumulativeupdate5#2351584) - Fixes an issue where high `PREEMPTIVE_OS_QUERYREGISTRY` waits occur. To apply this fix, you need to turn on trace flag 12502, which is used to disable external authorization policies for on-premises SQL Server instances.

[Cumulative update 5 for SQL Server 2022 (KB5026806)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2022/cumulativeupdate5)

When the trace flag is off, and we run our test queries, we can monitor thousands (411k to be precise) of hits to the local registry looking for an Azure Purview related configuration. Enabling the flag stops the registry hit and makes our query run in seconds again.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.DEV\MSSQLServer\PurviewConfig
Result NAME NOT FOUND
```

Answer (score -2):

Using trace flag 9481 seems to resolve this issue for me.

The CE (Cardinality Estimator) in 2014 (compat 120) changed from 2012 and 2008, and using TF 9481 forces use of the 2012 CE.

See [The SQL 2014 Cardinality Estimator Eats Bad TSQL for Breakfast](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/04/sql-2014-cardinality-estimator-eats-bad-tsql-breakfast/) by Kendra Little.